# How to measure salinity?

Tags: sensor

I have to measure salinity of a brine in the range from 1500 to 3500 ppm.
Temperature of the brine is between 22 and 40 deg C. Measurement probe has to be galvanicaly isolated from the brine - no direct contact allowed. However sensor in plastic and immersing is fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Salinity can be measured from the index of refraction of light - that would satisfy your sensor isolation requirement. There are commercially available digital refractometers out there.

Comment: Youv'e got: conductivity, specific gravity, speed of sound, and index of refraction to choose from. Time to 'fess up, why do you need to measure salinity? That can help narrow down the choice, as each has it's complications, some of which might be useful.

Comment: To shed more light...  Salinity level in the salt-water pool has to be within certain limits. Too salty - too corrosive and you can taste the salt, If not enough then sanitizer production may not be adequate.  Salt concentration changes with time as in the case of outdoor pool you may have water coming in due to rain or coming out due to splash-out. Now, if you add more water then salinity will change. Of course the change will not be dramatic, but if done frequently enough and over longer time period - say a few months then everything adds up...

Comment: Ok. So you probably will not have weird ions to confuse a conductivity reading, and anything that contributes to conductivity is probably related to what you want to control. So a capacitive bridge will work. We used drexelbrook probes for level sensing, probably one could be adaped.

Answer (score 2):

Conductivity, it appears, is not the best way to measure salinity, [there are questions of which ion, etc](http://www.deltaenvironmental.com.au/management/Lab_methods/Specific_gravity.htm).

Instead, measure specific gravity. I get about Sg of 1.02 for your 3500 ppm.

[Here is a commercial unit](http://www.gardco.com/pages/density/electric_hydrometer.cfm). It looks like they have the classic floating bobber sg meter, with a little magnet in it to read the position. I suppose you could make a custom bobber by filling a glass ball with just the right solution, probably just di water, and connect a sensitive gram weight scale to it.

The whole thing would need a pretty good 'still well' where water currents do not push your probe around.

Comment: Ph will interfere with conductivity vs salinity, too.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason I'm assuming this is some sort of process fluid that you are trying to control, in this case measuring it's specific gravity might be a bit difficult.

I would suggest measuring it's speed of sound. There seems to have been a lot of research on accurately measuring the speed of sound in sea water based on temperature, pressure, and salinity. Maybe you can adapt this to measuring your brine. Take a look at [this](http://www.dtic.mil/cgi-bin/GetTRDoc?AD=ADB199453&Location=U2&doc=GetTRDoc.pdf), Volume 1, Speed of sound in sea water

Luckily the research was conducted within both your 20-40C and salinity range.

Comment: An underwater whistle! Two, one with di water, and measure the beat note.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to measure salinity is the conductance and the dissipation factor at microwave levels.

Can you use carbon or gold wire electrodes?

If yes I might consider measuring the conductance between a carbon filter and a carbon rod?

Answer (score 0):

As the measurement probe has to be isolated from the solution, you have to measure its conductance without connecting to it. I'm thinking you'll need to use AC measurements, looking for loss due to increasing conductivity. Either 2 coils separated by a space filled with fluid, looking at the changes in mutual inductance between them, or 2 metal plates forming a capacitor (insulator between and around them) in an AC bridge such as a Wien bridge. Beyond suggesting frequencies in the 100kHz region as being easy to deal with in a bridge, I can't suggest anything more specific.